# Can FOR XML PATH return NULL for an empty resultset?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I would think this query

```
select null for xml path('foo')
```

would return NULL, but actuality

```
<foo/ >
```

is returned. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

To clarify, the behavior I would expect to see is demonstrated in this example

```
SELECT
'foo' WHERE 1=0
for xml path('Outer'), type
```

This returns a different result and I'm not understanding why.

```
SELECT
(SELECT 'foo' WHERE 1=0)
for xml path('Outer'), type
```

My real world query is an xml subquery, but the example is valid either way.

```
SELECT
(SELECT 'foo' WHERE 1=0 FOR XML PATH ('Inner'),type)
for xml path('Outer'), type
```

This query works in the simplest case, but does not allow adding attributes to the root element, which is required in my case.

```
SELECT 'foo' WHERE 1=0 FOR XML PATH ('Inner'),root('outer'),type
```

Comment: I don't understand what issue you have here. If you could add sample table(s) and the desired XML result using that data it might be easier to understand how you need to write your query to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [value(method)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.110).aspx). From MSDN:

> You typically use this method to extract a value from an XML instance stored in an xml type column, parameter, or variable. In this way, you can specify SELECT queries that combine or compare XML data with data in non-XML columns.

Code:

```
DECLARE @variable_xml XML
DECLARE @variable_varchar VARCHAR(20)
SET @variable_xml = 'select NULL for xml path(''foo'')'
SET @variable_varchar = @variable_xml.value('(/Root)[1]',
                           'varchar')
SELECT  @variable_varchar
```

Output:
`NULL`

**EDIT:**

I may have misunderstood the question. Please comment and I will update or delete my answer if its incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

### **`ISNULL` Quick Answer**

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL,'NULL') FOR XML PATH('foo')
```

*This means if you want the XML element, etc. to have a value of `NULL` rather than being blank, then your `SELECT` statement would need to use the `ISNULL` function and say if the value is `NULL` then replace with literal `NULL` value to be as the actual XML value.*

---

### `ELEMENTS XSINIL`

Consider testing with the `ELEMENTS XSINIL` parameter too and see what results you get with your `FOR XML PATH` logic. This may work for your need as well.

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL, 'NULL')
FOR XML PATH('foo')
    ,TYPE
    ,ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

***Resource:*** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178079.aspx

> The ELEMENTS directive constructs XML in which each column value maps
>   to an element in the XML. If the column value is NULL, no element is
>   added. By specifying the optional XSINIL parameter on the ELEMENTS
>   directive, you can request that an element also be created for the
>   NULL value. In this case, an element that has the xsi:nil attribute
>   set to TRUE is returned for each NULL column value.

Answer (score 0):

XML treats null as an empty string. You could try `WHERE 1=2` so that there are no rows.

Comment: It was a mistake to use null in my example. I clarified above based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do this way

```
select
(
    select
    (select 'foo' for xml path ('Inner'), type)
    , (select 'foo' for xml path ('Inner2'), type)
    for xml path (''), type
)
for xml path ('Outer')
```

which gives you next XML

```
<Outer>
  <Inner>foo</Inner>
  <Inner2>foo</Inner2>
</Outer>
```

and in the case with null values

```
select
(
    select
    (select null for xml path ('Inner'), type)
    , (select null for xml path ('Inner2'), type)
    for xml path (''), type
)
for xml path ('Outer')
```

it returns "unwanted" empty inner elements

```
<Outer>
  <Inner />
  <Inner2 />
</Outer>
```

OR!!! you can do this way

```
select
(
    select
    (select 'foo' [Inner] for xml path (''), type)
    , (select 'foo' [Inner2] for xml path (''), type)
    for xml path (''), type
)
for xml path ('Outer')
```

with the same results when there are non NULL values

```
<Outer>
  <Inner>foo</Inner>
  <Inner2>foo</Inner2>
</Outer>
```

BUT with no "unwanted" inner elements when the values are NULL

```
select
(
    select
    (select null [Inner] for xml path (''), type)
    , (select null [Inner2] for xml path (''), type)
    for xml path (''), type
)
for xml path ('Outer')
```

result

```
<Outer></Outer>
```